# C++ Error Handling - downside of using std::pair or std::tuple for returning error codes and function returns

Tags: c++, error-handling, tuples, return-value, std-pair

Without getting into the general exceptions vs error codes discussion, what do you think are the downsides of using `std::pair` or `std:tuple` for returning multiple values, namely the function's return value AND the error/success code, similar to how many [Go developers apparently do error handling](http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/why-not-go/240005062)?

This approach obviously has the advantage of not having to use out parameters for the function return value or error code (depending on which way around you prefer it).

Comment: Check out the old Barton/Nackman **`Fallible`** class, or more modern version like Boost **`optional`**

Comment: @close-voters: please only vote to close questions that you understand. do not vote to close merely because you **fail to understand** the question. failure to understand does not mean that you're competent to vote on it: it means the opposite

Comment: Fun fact -- most usable, rich, and educating questions on CO are closed, "not constructive", "too broad", etc. Since the thread is now closed, another downside of tuple -- memory overhead. **Always**. With exception, the exception mechanism only kicks in if there is an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “what do you think are the downsides of using std::pair or std:tuple for returning multiple values, namely the function's return value AND the error/success code”

The main downside of that simplistic (C level) approach to failure handling is a

- loss of safety.

I.e. there's *more that can go wrong*, such as accessing an indeterminate result value. Or just using a return value when the function didn't produce a meaningful one.

The old Barton & Nackman **`Fallow`** class solved this safety problem by restricting access to the result value. Essentially the calling code has to check if there *is*  a result value, before using it, and using a logically non-existent result value causes an exception or termination. The **`boost::optional`** class does much the same.

If you don't want a dependency on Boost, then an `Optional` class is trivial to implement for POD result type, and at a cost of a little possible inefficiency (dynamic allocation) you can just use a `std::vector` to carry a non-POD possible result.

The challenge is to retain the clarity of the calling code, which is the whole point of the exercise…

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose, in most cases I use an own wrapper type which introduces some syntactic sugar. Let's see an example:

```
template <class T>
struct Result
{
public:
    enum Status {
        Success,
        Error
    };

    // Feel free to change the default behavior... I use implicit
    // constructors for type T for syntactic sugar in return statements.
    Result(T resultValue) : s(Success), v(resultValue) {}
    explicit Result(Status status, std::string errMsg = std::string()) : s(status), v(), errMsg(errMsg) {}
    Result() : s(Error), v() {} // Error without message

    // Explicit error with message
    static Result error(std::string errMsg) { return Result(Error, errMsg); }

    // Implicit conversion to type T
    operator T() const { return v; }
    // Explicit conversion to type T
    T value() const { return v; }

    Status status() const { return s; }
    bool isError() const { return s == Error; }
    bool isSuccessful() const { return s == Success; }
    std::string errorMessage() const { return errMsg; }

private:
    T v;
    Status s;

    // if you want to provide error messages:
    std::string errMsg;
};
```

Then, simply use this class as the return value in your methods which can return errors:

```
Result<int> fac(int n) {
    if(n < 0)
        return Result<int>::error("n has to be greater or equal zero!");
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    if(n > 0)
        return n * fac(n-1);  // gets automatically converted to int
}
```

Of course this implementation of the factorial function is horrible, but demonstrates the conversion without bothering about the error-extended return type we use.

Example usage:

```
int main() {
    for(int i = -3; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        Result<int> r = fac(i);
        std::cout << i << " | ";
        std::cout << (r.isSuccessful() ? "ok" : "error") << " | ";
        if(r.isSuccessful())
            std::cout << r.value();
        else
            std::cout << r.errorMessage();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-3 | error | n has to be greater or equal zero!
-2 | error | n has to be greater or equal zero!
-1 | error | n has to be greater or equal zero!
0 | ok | 1
1 | ok | 1
2 | ok | 2
3 | ok | 6
```

One big advantage of the custom type is that you can insert some control ensuring that the client code **always checks for errors before accessing the actual value** and only accesses the value if it was successful respectively the error message if it wasn't. For this, we can extend the class by the following:

```
struct Result
{
public:
    // in all constructors, add:
    Result(...) : ..., checked(false) {...}

    // in the error checker methods, add: (and drop const-ness)
    bool is...() { checked = true; return ... }

    // rewrite the value conversion as follows:
    operator T() const { std::assert(checked && isSuccessful()); return v; }
    T value() const    { std::assert(checked && isSuccessful()); return v; }

    // rewrite the errorMessage-getter as follows:
    std::string errorMessage() const { std::assert(checked && isError()); return errMsg; }

private:
    ...
    bool checked;
};
```

You might want to make the class definition depending on the build mode (debug build / release build).

Note that the example has to be rewritten as follows:

```
Result<int> fac(int n) {
    if(n < 0)
        return Result<int>::error("n has to be greater or equal zero!");
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    if(n > 0) {
        Result<int> r = fac(n - 1);
        if(r.isError()) return r;  // propagate error (similar to exceptions)
        return n * r;              // r gets automatically converted to int
    }
}
```

The main-code from above is still valid, as it already did error-checking before accessing the value / the error message.

Comment: `v` still has to be constructed (a major downside to multi-returns), using something like `std::aligned_storage` and placement newing would be a better bet, or just use `Boost.Optional` which already does this, and having an error message seems to be pushing it's boundaries into exception territory.

Comment: Sometimes I don't want to use boost. And sometimes (if not in 99% of the cases), the performance downside doesn't matter. However, thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 2):

This "idiom" is good because both the type and succes indicator are return values of the function. Failure might not be exceptional, so exceptions are inappropriate sometimes.

The downside however is that you have to split out the two return types. This can be ugly; using `std::tie` helps but you are unable to construct from multiple return.

```
bool success;
std::string value;
std::tie(success, value)=try_my_func();
```

This is quite verbose.

Second, if one of the types is "optional" depending on the value of another element in the tuple then it still has to be constructed which for some types is still very wasteful.

If you are using the idiom a lot, consider instead using something like the `boost::optional` type. This is close to the haskel maybe than go's multiple return.

#### Reference

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Agreed that handling the return is unwieldy. An alternative is `auto result = try_my_func(); if (result.first) { std::string &value = result.second; ... }`, and that's a bit more natural in some circumstances.

Comment: @SteveJessop yes, using auto helps a bit, but I find the taking the reference stuff very "noisy", hopefully being able to construct from a tuples will be added to the language one day.

Comment: In practice I might not bother with the reference if the value is only used a couple of times in the following code. Just write `result.second` a couple of times: it's annoying but not annoying enough to do anything about it :-)

Comment: @111111, I suppose you could do it with a macro, something like `#define DECL_TIE(X, Y, EXPR) auto result = EXPR;auto& X = result.first; auto& Y = result.second` except of course you'd want to use some kind of gensym for `result` (`CONCAT(result__,__LINE__)`, for example)

Comment: @rici you could, I am not sure I could bring myself to use a MACRO where when a little verbosity is require, it still doesn't eliminate the default construction.

Comment: @111111, just think of MACRO as a primitive template implementation :)  and use simple macros and complex templates. You're right about the default construction, which is an argument in favour of always designing classes with a really cheap default constructor. That's got to be a design principle somewhere; you always seem to be working around some library feature or other when you try to avoid default construction. FWIW. (I'd like to see the language feature, too, by the way: has it been proposed?)

Comment: @rici not sure, unless they add that MACRO it would have to be a language feature and "they" seem very reluctant to do that. It's not the end of the world, I would far rather they concentrate on important stuff like real UTF8 support.

Comment: This has since been added as a language feature: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding
e.g. `auto [success, value] = try_my_func()`

Answer (score 0):

It's better than regular error codes because you don't have to waste your life with out parameters. But it still retains all of the very serious downsides.

Really, it's just a micro change, it's still error codes- there's no significant benefit.

Comment: using e.g. `boost::optional` allows a function to sometimes have "no result produced" as part of its normal invocation contract, while retaining the safety of exceptions. using a normal return also for the "no result produced" case can be important for the clarity of the calling code. but it depends...

Comment: for those who don't want to add a dependency on Boost: `optional` is trivial to implement for POD type, and for non-POD one can simply use a single-item `std::vector` to transfer the possible value. in the case of no value that vector is simply empty (essentially doing it this way one avoids a dependency and gets simple code at the cost of a possible dynamic allocation).