# Function with a custom return type and the "false" return conditions?

Tags: c++

I have a function that returns a custom class structure, but how should I handle the cases where I wish to inform the user that the function has failed, as in return `false`.

My function looks something like this:

```
Cell CSV::Find(std::string segment) {
  Cell result;
  // Search code here.
  return result;
}
```

So when succesful, it returns the proper result, but how should I handle the case when it could fail?

I thought about adding a boolean method inside Cell to check what ever `Cell.data` is empty or not (`Cell.IsEmpty()`). But am I thinking this issue in a way too complicated way?

Comment: `std::string segment` -> `const std::string& segment`- Saves on copying

Comment: @EdHeal Depends on what you do with the argument. If you move it into a newly constructed object, for example, pass-by-value is more efficient.

Comment: @Angew - I would have thought as it is searching (as per comment) that a copy is not required

Comment: @EdHeal True indeed; in this particular case, a `const &` is probably in order. I just wanted to point out that it's not an "applies everywhere" rule.

Comment: Thank you both for mentioning the use of reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the right approach to return error codes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157098/whats-the-right-approach-to-return-error-codes-in-c)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are three general approaches:

- Use exceptions. This is what's in Bathsheba's answer.
- Return [`std::optional<Cell>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (or some other type which may or may not hold an actual `Cell`).
- Return `bool`, and add a `Cell &` parameter.

Which of these is best depends on how you intend this function to be used. If the primary use case is passing a valid segment, then by all means use exceptions.

If part of the design of this function is that it can be used to tell if a segment is valid, exceptions aren't appropriate, and my preferred choice would be `std::optional<Cell>`. This may not be available on your standard library implementation yet (it's a C++17 feature); if not, [`boost::optional<Cell>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) may be useful (as mentioned in Richard Hodges's answer).

In the comments, instead of `std::optional<Cell>`, user You suggested [`expected<Cell, error>`](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/optional-expected/) (not standard C++, but proposed for a future standard, and implementable outside of the `std` namespace until then). This may be a good option to add some indication on why no `Cell` could be found for the `segment` parameter passed in, if there are multiple possible reasons.

The third option I include mainly for completeness. I do not recommend it. It's a popular and generally good pattern in other languages.

Comment: You mentioned that you do not recommend the third option? I see it used a lot on OS level operations. Where variables are predefined and functions will write directly in to them via reference, so they usually return only a boolean value to see what ever they succeeded or not.

Comment: @Mikko-PenttiEinariEronen OS-level operations are generally designed to be callable from any language. One popular language, C, doesn't have exceptions or any `optional` type, so the third option is the only one that remains.

Comment: There's a fourth way (or perhaps a variant of the `std::optional` approach): [`expected<Cell, error>`](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/optional-expected/) (a more formalized variant of what @manilo's answer suggests).

Comment: @You're right. I would classify that as a variant of `optional`, but it is a good option to mention regardless, thanks. Will edit.

Comment: That is a very elegant statement about exceptions: "If part of the design of this function is that it can be used to tell if ... is valid, exceptions aren't appropriate."

Comment: The third option I've seen a lot in C#. Within those standards, it would usually be a `bool TryFind(string, Cell &)`. So where something would normally throw an exception, it instead returns false. Like with C#'s [Dictionary.TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @AlecGordon Right, that's one language where I agree it's appropriate. Two things that make it appropriate there, to me, and not in C++: in C#, if it fails, the variable can be set to `default(Cell)` (typically `null`) to put the variable in a well-defined state, and C# has `out`, which means the cell doesn't need to be initialised prior to the call. In C++, if `false` would be returned, you pretty much have no option but to leave the object in its prior state. If the prior state is uninitialised, then this is a recipe for accidental UB of the worst kind (highly unpredictable at runtime).

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that exceptions should also only be considered if the rest of the code base is exception safe?

Comment: @jpmc26 It's perfectly fine if some part of the rest of the code base isn't exception safe, as long as it's some part that wouldn't end up seeing the exception. Perhaps it's code that never ends up calling `Find`, not even indirectly. Perhaps it's code that does end up calling `Find`, but something catches and handles the exception before it ends up back there.

Answer (score 7):

Is this function a query, which could validly not find the cell, or is it an imperative, where the cell is expected to be found?

If the former, return an optional (or nullable pointer to) the cell.

If the latter, throw an exception if not found.

Former:

```
boost::optional<Cell> CSV::Find(std::string segment) {
  boost::optional<Cell> result;
  // Search code here.
  return result;
}
```

Latter:
as you have it.

And of course there is the c++17 variant-based approach:

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>

struct CellNotFound {};
struct Cell {};

using CellFindResult = std::variant<CellNotFound, Cell>;


CellFindResult Find(std::string segment) {
  CellFindResult result { CellNotFound {} };

  // Search code here.
  return result;
}

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

void cellsAndStuff()
{
    std::visit(overloaded
    {
        [&](CellNotFound)
        {
            // the not-found code
        },
        [&](Cell c)
        {
            // code on cell found
        }
    }, Find("foo"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The C++ way of dealing with abject failures is to define an exception class of the form:

```
struct CSVException : std::exception{};
```

In your function you then `throw` one of those in the failure branch:

```
Cell CSV::Find(std::string segment) {
  Cell result;
  // Search code here.
  if (fail) throw CSVException();
  return result;
}
```

You then handle the fail case with a `try` `catch` block at the calling site.

If however the "fail" branch is normal behaviour (subjective indeed but only you can be the judge of normality), then do indeed imbue some kind of failure indicator inside `Cell`, or perhaps even change the return type to `std::optional<Cell>`.

Comment: An exception is appropriate if the caller should reasonably demand that the cell be found. Ideally we wouldn't throw in the case of a failed query.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++17, another approach would be to use an [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) type as your return value. That's a wrapper that may or may not contain a value. The caller can then check whether your function actually returned a value and handle the case where it didn't.

```
std::optional<Cell> CSV::Find(std::string segment) {
  Cell result;
  // Search code here.
  return result;
}

void clientCode() {
   auto cell = CSV::Find("foo");
   if (cell)
      // do stuff when found
   else
      // handle not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A further option is using multiple return values:

```
std::pair<Cell, bool> CSV::Find(std::string segment) {
  Cell result;
  // Search code here.
  return {result, found};
}

// ...

auto cell = CSV::Find("foo");
if (cell->second)
  // do stuff with cell->first
```

The boolean flag says whether the requested `Cell` was found or not.

PROs

- well known approach (e.g. [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert));
- quite direct: value and success indicator are return values of the function.

CONs

- obscureness of `first` and `second` which requires to always remember the relative positions of values within the pairs. C++17 [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) / [if statement with initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) partially resolve this issue:

  ```
  if (auto [result, found] = CSV::Find("foo"); found)
    // do stuff with `result`
  ```
- possible loss of safety (the calling code has to check if there is a result value, before using it).

#### Details

- [Returning multiple values from functions in C++](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/returning-multiple-values-from-functions-in-c/)
- [C++ Error Handling - downside of using std::pair or std::tuple for returning error codes and function returns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13777987/3235496)

Answer (score 0):

For parsing, it is generally better to avoid `std::string` and instead use [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view); if C++17 is not available, minimally functional versions can be whipped up easily enough.

Furthermore, it is also important to track not only *what was parsed* but also *the remainder*.

There are two possibilities to track the remainder:

- taking a mutable argument (by reference),
- returning the remainder.

I personally prefer the latter, as in case of errors it guarantees that the caller has in its hands a unmodified value which is useful for error-reporting.

---

Then, you need to examine what potential errors can occur, and what recovery mechanisms you wish for. This will inform the design.

For example, if you wish to be able to parse ill-formed CSV documents, then it is reasonable that `Cell` be able to represent ill-formed CSV cells, in which case the interface is rather simple:

```
std::pair<Cell, std::string_view> consume_cell(std::string_view input) noexcept;
```

Where the function *always* advances and the `Cell` *may* contain either a proper cell, or an ill-formed one.

On the other hand, if you only wish to support well-formed CSV documents, then it is reasonable to signal errors via exceptions and that `Cell` only be able to hold actual cells:

```
std::pair<std::optional<Cell>, std::string_view> consume_cell(...);
```

---

And finally, you need to think about how to signal *end of row* conditions. It may a simple marker on `Cell`, though at this point I personally prefer to create an *iterator* as it presents a more natural interface since a row is a range of `Cell`.

The C++ interface for iterators is a bit clunky (as you need an "end", and the end is unknown before parsing), however I recommend sticking to it to be able to use the iterator with `for` loops. If you wish to depart from it, though, at least make it work easily with `while`, such as `std::optional<Cell> cell; while ((cell = row.next())) { ... }`.